# JSON return data is always null from WebService (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, ajax, json

I have stepped through my WebServices code to validate that I am actually returning data, but when I check the return on the JSON side, it always says "null."

Here is a snippet of the WebService code.

**UPDATED**: To simplify things greatly, I'm returning a simple List from the web service instead of a custom object, and I've condensed the AJAX call as well.

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

        public List<string> GetLocations(string CustomerID)
        {
            List<string> LocationsList = new List<string>();

            string sql = "select customer_site from demand_addresses where customer_identifier=" + CustomerID;
            if (gDB.ExecuteRet(sql, "DB"))
            {

                DataTable dt = gDB.GetResultDataSet(0);
                int i = 0;
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        LocationsList.Add(rs["customer_site"].ToString());
                    }
                }  
                else
                {
                    LocationsList.Add("No Data Found.");
                }

                return LocationsList;
            }
            else
            {

                LocationsList.Add("No Data Found.");
                return LocationsList;

            }
```

And here is the AJAX call (**UPDATED** to reflect Kami's comments below):

```
          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "/webservices/services.asmx/GetLocations",
                              data: "{ 'CustomerID': '" + selectedCustomer + "' }",               
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",               
                              dataType: "json",               
                              success: function (data) { alert(data.d); },               
                              error: function (status) {alert(status);}
           });
```

The "alert(data.d)" line results in "TypeError: data is null", and if I change it to "alert(data)" I simply get an alert box that says "null."

I need help understanding why the web service is properly returning data, but it's not making it back to AJAX/JSON.

Comment: So, using something like firebug or fiddler, can you tell what the exact response is from the server?

Comment: Trying firebug - the page refreshes so fast all I can see is "Internal Server Error."

Comment: Your response format is json(`ResponseFormat.Json`). But what your service expects as RequestFormat Xml or Json? Or maybe it expects the argument in the url as GET method

Comment: "the page refreshes so fast all I can see is "Internal Server Error." Huh? It's an ajax call, what do you mean the page refreshes?

Comment: This is part of a dynamic-dropdown process. User selects "Customer" from drop-down, then this code gets triggered to get Locations by customer. When I select the Customer (watching firebug) I can see the console message "Internal Server Error" for about .03 seconds and then it disappears.

Comment: uhhh weird. Download fiddler. :)

Answer (score -2):

You are not passing the variable to the `OnSuccess` function.

Also, I have had issues in the past where you need to use an anonymous function to call your subfunction.

Try something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservices/services.asmx/GetLocations",
    data: "{ 'CustomerID': '" + selectedCustomer + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, resp) { OnSuccess(data,resp)}, // anon function may be needed
    error: function(data,resp) { OnError(data,resp)}
});
```

Comment: Right, good catch. Still, I changed the AJAX code to success: function (data) { successFunc(data); }, and set up a function, function successFunc(data) { alert(data); } -- and this alert still comes back null. If I change to alert(data.d) it says "cannot read property 'd'".

Answer (score -2):

I was working on wcf webservice a days back and same was happening to me. At the final return statement everything was working fine. The data was there but when i saw it on the other side there was nothing.

The problem was custom object (in your case LOCATION) had a nullable property but was not defined as nullable. I did that and it started working. I am still not sure why but you should try it once.

```
public class Location
    {
        public string? customer_identifier { get; set; }
        public string[]? customer_site { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I got rid of customer_identifier for now, b/c I don't need it at this point. I changed customer_site to "public string?[] customer_site { get; set; }" and that resulted in the compile error "The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>"

Comment: ahan. I read on the internet now, since string is already nullable so putting ? will through an error. .. ok so, now we should try to minimize the problem. As other users suggested try with fiddler.